# how to get all file full paths with swift in a folder

Tags: swift

Im trying to recursively get all files paths so that i could process them, im sure it's trivial to many, but I'm still new to swift, please bear with me.

```
let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(atPath: arguments.get(fileName)![0])

while let element = enumerator?.nextObject() as? String {
         print(element)
    }
```

the above code only gives a list of file names without real full paths

```
file1.txt
file2.txt 
file3.txt
```

structure is

```
-- folder1
    --file1.txt
    --file2.txt
    -- folder2
       --file3.txt
```

but file3.txt is actually in folder1/folder2

how do i get something like this with swift?

```
/full/path/folder1/file1.txt
/full/path/folder1/file2.txt
/full/path/folder1/folder2/file3.txt
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `fm` is our file manager and `url` is our directory URL.

```
let dir = fm.enumerator(at:url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)! 
for case let f as URL in dir {
    print(f) // or its absolute path or whatever
}
```

Here's a test:

```
let fm = FileManager.default
let docs = fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let f1 = docs.appendingPathComponent("f1.txt")
try? "howdy".write(to: f1, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
let subdir = docs.appendingPathComponent("subdir")
try? fm.createDirectory(at: subdir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
let f2 = subdir.appendingPathComponent("f2.txt")
try? "hello".write(to: f2, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)

let dir = fm.enumerator(at:docs, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)!
for case let f as URL in dir where f.pathExtension == "txt" {
    print(f) // or its absolute path or whatever
}
```

Result:

```
file:///.../Documents/f1.txt
file:///.../Documents/subdir/f2.txt
```

I believe that matches your requirements.

Comment: ` f as URL ` gives me 'URL' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context error

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like now. I've shown you my code and I assure you it both compiles and works.

Comment: it's weird, i changed URL to NSURL, it does give me all files in folder1, but not folder2 though

Comment: I still don't know what your new code looks like now. If you want more help, edit your question to show it. — The notion that `URL` could be ambiguous suggests you may be using some sort of framework or extension that is messing you up. Perhaps you should be asking a separate question about _that_ if you can't track it down.

Comment: I have added even more code to prove that this works as desired.

Comment: @matt If you are using the SPM Utility portion of Swift Package Manager (handy for command line tools), it defines a `struct URL` that conflicts with Foundation's `struct URL`.  `Foundation.URL` seems to be the way to disambiguate, though I wish (maybe there is?) there was a way to say "Just use only Foundation.URL throughout this compilation unit".

Comment: @bbum Yes, some languages let you say `with` or similar to namespace a stretch of code. Can't do that in Swift. Very interesting about the SPM Utility, I had no idea. Maybe that deserves a bug report?

Comment: Yes, it likely is.  I'll follow up with the maintainer post vacation.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your `NSEnumerator` `allObjects` property, cast them from `[Any]` to `[URL]` and use `compactMap` to return all file URLs that are not directories and not hidden:

```
let documentsDir =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

// check if the url is a directory
if documentsDir.hasDirectoryPath {
    // get all non directory paths from your enumerator
    let contents = (FileManager.default.enumerator(at: documentsDir, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)?.allObjects as? [URL])?.lazy.compactMap {
        $0.hasDirectoryPath ? nil : $0.path
    } ?? []
    print(contents.count)
}
```